# polynomial curve fitting and linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

In this text, why does the polynomial equation have to be to the $4$th degree? Why couldn't all $5$ points lie on a polynomial of say degree $2$?

[image]

Comment: Instead of a system of linear equations I find the Newton's formula to be easy to apply and considerably faster.

Comment: @szw1710 Interesting, but how is it relevant to this example from a linear algebra text?

Comment: The example origins from a linear algebra course. But I am afraid of the impression this is the only method of solving the problem. I simply turn attention to another one, which is in my opinion simpler. If OP wants, he/she will read about it.

Answer (score 2):

They *might* lie on a quadratic, but in general they will not.  If you fit five points that happen to lie on a quadratic using a 4th-order polynomial, your fit will be:

$$0 x^4 + 0 x^3 + a x^2 + b x + c$$

Comment: But it is actually impossible. The fitting polynomial of $4$th order is uniquely determined. I think this is you wanted to say. This is the reason why our points do not lie on a parabola.

Answer (score 0):

The $5$ and $2$ in the question body are *irrelevant* to the *general* problem of [Legendre polynomial interpolation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html).

To give a *general* answer, consider a set of $m$ *distinct* points on $\Bbb R^2$: $\{(x_i,y_i)\}_{i = 1,\dots,m}$.  We want an interpolating polynomial $f(X)$ of degree $d$ in $X$ with real coefficients
$$f(X) = \sum_{j=0}^d a_j X^j, \quad a_j \in \Bbb{R}$$
so that
$$\forall i \in \{1,\dots,m\}, \quad y_i = f(x_i) = \sum_{j=0}^d a_j x_i^j. \tag1\label1$$

OP asks why $d$ is chosen to be $m-1$?

To see this, rewrite \eqref{1} into $Y = Xa$, where
$Y = (y_1,\dots,y_m)^T$, $a = (a_0,\dots,a_d)^T$ and the $m \times (d+1)$ matrix $X = (x_i^j)_{(i,j)\in\{1,\dots,m\}\times\{0,\dots,d\}}$.  The question becomes solving for $a$ in this condensed equation.

This is solvable as long as the column vector $y$ (, which collects the given $y$-coordinates,) is in the column space of $X$.

In [linear-programming](/questions/tagged/linear-programming), matrix $X$ often has *more columns than rows*.  Contrarily, in [statistics](/questions/tagged/statistics), matrix $X$ often has *more rows than columns*, so they have to think of [pseudoinverse $X^+$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse).  Despite $ XX^{+}X=X$ and $ X^{+}XX^{+}=X^{+}$, we *can't* say that $a = X^{+}Y$.  In general $X(X^+Y) \ne Y$, it only minimizes the error (in the sense of Euclidean norm)
$$X^+Y \in \mathop{\mathrm{argmin}}_{a \in \Bbb{R}^{d+1}}||Y-Xa||_2.$$
If $X$ has linearly independent rows, $XX^+=I$.  A square matrix is a minimal choice.  Luckily, if $X$ is a square matrix, then $\det(X)$ is just the Vendermonde determinant, which is nonzero, so $a = X^{-1}y$.